# Magento 1.13.1.0 "customer_entity" table add "last login date time"?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.13

Magento Admin created new column in customer_entity table named "login_at" to store last login date time.

Column is created but not able to insert data into that column on Login?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

I know there is "log/customer' table for it but requirement is to disable Logs and add insert value into "customer_entity" table.

Thanks,
Preethy

Answer (score 1):

This is how my logic is.

1. override the admin user login success action. create a new custom dispatch event and trigger an observer when the login is success.
2. Now in that observer capture the current time through `DateTime` function.
3. Now capture this value in a variable and load the admin user object and save this variable in ur custom column. 
   **NOTE:** Check whether the value is available or not. If yes, then you need to override the value.

Let me know if you need any more.

Comment: Thanks so much will try this way!